# Trying to use matcaffe for the interface between MATLAB and Caffe, but cannot find caffe_.cpp

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

With `caffe_.cpp` being a private function, when I call functions like `caffe.reset_all()`, there is always an error telling me it cannot find `caffe_.cpp`.

So how to use that in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `'caffe_.cpp'` under [`matlab/+caffe/private/`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/matlab/%2Bcaffe/private).
Make sure you cloned caffe git properly and that you built the matlab interface:

```
~$ make matcaffe
```